# Is <> 0 condition will Consider Null & 0 as same in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I need to compare variable in case condition in stored procedure.

```
case when @column <> 0 then ...
     ELSE 0 END
```

but whenever am getting @column as `NULL`, then the above script returning as 0.

will sql consider both `0` & `NULL` as same.

Am using sql server 2014.

Thanks All

Comment: 0 and NULL is not same in SQL Server. So you have to set CASE statement accordingly.

Comment: What result do you expect in case the value is `NULL`?

Comment: when column is 0 then only i have to show 0. If it is other than 0 i have show column value. why condition returning 0 when column is having NULL value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SQL considers `NULL` as "I have no idea". Comparing anything with "I have no idea" results in an answer of "I totally have no idea". Look:

> - How high is John?
>   - I have no idea.
>   - What is two centimeters higher than John?
>   - I have no idea.

Even comparison between two `NULL` values is not true: if I have no idea how tall John is and if I *also* have no idea how tall Jack is, I can't conclude that John is equally tall as Jack (and I can't conclude that John is *not* equally tall as Jack). The only sensible answer is... "I have no idea".

The way to test for `NULL` is with `IS` operator, which specifically exists for this scenario (e.g. `@column IS NULL`, or `@column IS NOT NULL`).

So `NULL` is not equal to `0`, nor is it NOT equal to `0`. The result of `NULL <> 0` is `NULL`. However, `NULL` is falsy where conditionals are concerned, so `CASE` thinks you should get the `ELSE` branch any time `@column` is `NULL`.

Comment: I wanted to close the question as a duplicate (which it is many times over), but it seems to be the best quality question *and* answer, so... +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to execute the `then` part of `case` if the `column` value is `null`, then modify your condition to check for `nulls` also

```
CASE WHEN (@column <> 0 OR @column IS NULL) then ...
     ELSE 0 END
```